# xmlhttprequest not working with all browser

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I want to fetch feeds in my webpage. The feed link is : [News](http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533916/index.rss). I have tried this code :

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gmail</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var xmlhttp;
            function fetchFeed(){
                if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533916/index.rss",
                        success: function(xml) {
                            var i=0;
                            alert($(xml).find('item').length);
                            $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                                alert($(this).find('title').text());
                                i++;
                            });
                        },
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("XMLHttpRequest: " + XMLHttpRequest + "\nTextStatus : " + textStatus + "\nError Thrown: " + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="gmailForm"></div>
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="fetchFeed()"/>


    </body>
</html>
```

Well, this works properly in IE & gives output as : 
[image: ie]

But, not working in Chrome : 
[image: chrome]

& also not in FireFox : 
[image: firefox]

Where is my error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This: `url: "http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533916/index.rss"`

I'm guessing you are not the *Times of India*.

You're bumping against the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Basically, you can only do XMLHttpRequest to the same server the page comes from. It should not even work in IE unless you set the security policy very, very low.

You need to proxy the request on your server either via mod_rewrite/mod_proxy or use a cgi script.

Here's a nice article on YAHOO! Developer Network describing the problem and gives a simple PHP script to do the proxying: [JavaScript: Use a Web Proxy for Cross-Domain XMLHttpRequest Calls](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html)

Comment: Will $.get able to solve this problem ? or there is no solution ?

Comment: I mentioned the solution: you need to proxy the request on your server so that the browser thinks you are requesting it from your server when in fact all your server does is fetch it from timesofindia and forward it again to your browser.

Comment: I don't think this restriction is enforced for JSON (I'm doing it all the time with other domains), so maybe you should switch the format from XML to JSON. Which would be a good idea anyways.

Comment: @auco: The restriction is on domain access. It applies to JSON as well. You may be thinking of JSONP which is a convention to fetch data from foreign domains using the `<script>` tag instead of xmlhttprequest.

Comment: hmm, sorry, I haven't investigated this: but I'm constantly using XMLHttpRequest (native, not via jQuery) to send requests asking for JSON data to GoogleMaps, OSM, Flickr, Yahoo Pipes and others. Browsers: latest Firefox, Safari, Safari Mobile and Chrome. I do it from a local webpage or from my server. And it works! All the time. It would be a bit silly for all these nice services (like twitter and fb) to have JSON APIs if you wouldn't be able to use them.

Comment: @auco: At least one of your assertion is definitely false: you cannot get JSON data from Google Maps in JS using XMLHttpRequest. It doesn't work. Anyone (apart from you apparently, who appear to be an exception) can test it and see that what you're saying is plainly flase. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845265/javascript-xmlhttprequest-problem-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing

Comment: @auco: I checked Flickr as well. You can not get JSON data from JS using XMLHTTPrequest from Flickr so that's two assertions you've made that is plainly false. It appear that you have not been doing it from a local webpage or from your server after all otherwise you'd realize that Flickr and Google Maps don't work.

Comment: well, here's proof:http://jsfiddle.net/jy4jL/2/ -- (also works with Yahoo Pipes, Google Maps API - though you need an API key - and OSM). However, as you gave the answer already: the bottom line isn't then "no", it just depends on if the servers allow it or not. So, clearly the Times of India doesn't allow a cross-origin request.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery u don't have to care about XMLHttpRequest jquery will take care of it just use

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533916/index.rss",
                    success: function(xml) {
                        var i=0;
                        alert($(xml).find('item').length);
                        $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                            alert($(this).find('title').text());
                            i++;
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("XMLHttpRequest: " + XMLHttpRequest + "\nTextStatus : " + textStatus + "\nError Thrown: " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: No meaning ! even if I remove "if" ! It is already sending the request but Error is shown as outcome !

Comment: my point is if using jquery no need for this check if(window.XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: @Sarang: you can not send ajax request to a different domain url in you address bar is localhost while you are requesting at http://timesofindia.feedsportal.com/c/33039/f/533916/index.rss